# LinkedList without tail field gets stuck in infinite loop

Tags: java, while-loop, linked-list, nodes, do-while

What's wrong with my LinkedList add method if I want to implement it without a tail field?

```
public class LinkedList<E> {
    private Node<E> head= new Node<E>();
    private int size=0;
    public void linkedList(){
        head=null;
        size=0;
    }
    public void add(E data){
        Node<E> currNode=head;
        while (currNode.hasNext()){
            currNode.setNext(currNode.getNext());
        }
        Node<E> lastNode= new Node<E>();
        lastNode.setItem(data);
        lastNode.setNext(null);
        currNode.setNext(lastNode);
        size++;
    }

    public void remove(int i){
        Node<E> currNode = head;
        int index=0;
        while (index<i){
            currNode.setNext(currNode.getNext());
            i++;
        }
        currNode.setNext(currNode.getNext().getNext());

    }

    public void print(){
        Node<E> currNode = new Node<E>();
        do{
            System.out.println(currNode.getItem());

        } while (!currNode.hasNext());
    }


    public static void main(String arc[]){
        LinkedList<String> ll = new LinkedList<String>();
        ll.add("9");
        ll.add("b");
        ll.add("987");
        ll.print();
        return;
    }

}
```

Here's the `Node` class:

```
public class Node<E> {
    private E item;
    private Node<E> next;


    public Node<E> getNext(){
        return this.next;
    }
    public void setNext(Node<E> n){
        this.next=n;
    }

    public E getItem(){
        return this.item;
    }

    public void setItem(E item){
        this.item=item;
    }

    public boolean hasNext(){
        return (this.next != null);
    }
}
```

Edit: Changed the print method to:
public void print(){
        Node currNode = head;

```
    while (currNode.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(currNode.getItem());
        currNode=currNode.getNext();
    } 
}
```

and I get this result:

```
null
9
b
```

Comment: Stepping through in a debugger will probably answer this for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `add` method, don't you mean :

```
currNode = currNode.getNext();
```

instead of :

```
currNode.setNext(currNode.getNext());
```

? Because the last one has no effect and you are making an infinite loop...

Comment: after the fix you told, it just prints `null`. Thanks for clarification

Comment: Check your `print()` method.. you're not using `head` !

Comment: I wrote an update. Can you give me a hint why last item is not printed?

Comment: Because when `currNode` is last node, your `while (currNode.hasNext())` returns false.

Comment: Thank you :) I fixed that by `public void print(){
  Node<E> currNode = head;

  while (currNode.hasNext()){
   System.out.println(currNode.getItem());
   currNode=currNode.getNext();
  } 
  System.out.println(currNode.getItem());
 }` but why do I get a `null` in the beginning?

Comment: Moreover, to avoid the first `null` when printing, remove the initialization of `head` variable and/or fix your constructor : `public void linkedList()` is not a constructor and won't be called, `public LinkedList()` will.

Answer (score 1):

This block will never end

```
while (currNode.hasNext()) {
    currNode.setNext(currNode.getNext());
}
```

So infinite loop.

Make sure you move the currNode to forward, to reach the loop end by adding `crrNode.next()` inside the while loop.